# Как в OkHttp можно повторить запрос?

Tags: android, okhttp, try-catch

Я добавил Interceptor,но отрабатывает только onFailure()  и больше ничего(при намеренно отключенном интернете),значит нужно повторить запрос в onFailure,но как?

сам okhttp-клиент

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = null;
        boolean responseOK = false;
        int tryCount = 0;

        while (!responseOK && tryCount < 3) {
            try {
                response = chain.proceed(request);
                responseOK = response.isSuccessful();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("intercept", "Request is not successful - " + tryCount);
            }finally{
                tryCount++;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
})
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

и типичная работа с запросом/ответом

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            URL = getResources().getString(R.string.URL).concat(String.valueOf(counter));
                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "URL is correct");

                final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .get()
                        .build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "CANT DOWNLOAD DATA");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        //Working with data                            }

                });
                }

             sendBroadcast(dataIntent);


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете немного изменить код для достижения своей цели следующим образом:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Response response = null;
                    boolean responseOK = false;
                    int tryCount = 0;

                    while (!responseOK && tryCount < 3) {
                        try {
                            response = chain.proceed(request);
                            responseOK = response.isSuccessful();
                            Log.d("intercept", "Request is proceeded");
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("intercept", "Request is not successful - " + tryCount);
                        } finally{
                            tryCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            })
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .get()
                    .build();

client.newCall(request).execute();
```

При запуске этого кода в случае недоступности сети запрос будет отправлен три раза. Например, при запуске этого кода с отключённой передачей данных по мобильной сети в лог будет выведено:

> Request is not successful - 0
>
> Request is not successful - 1
>
> Request is not successful - 2

а при доступности сети:

> Request is proceeded

Т.е. [вместо `NetworkInterceptor` использовать просто `Interceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) (уровня приложения). Скорее всего, при запуске Вашего кода `NetworkInterceptor` вообще не вызывался, и, скорее всего, по следующей причине:

> Not invoked for cached responses that short-circuit the network.

Ну и после этого изменения в принципе уже не нужен колбэк, поэтому можно заменить

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "CANT DOWNLOAD DATA");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        //Working with data                            }

                });
```

на

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```